# TLSPhinx, Audio Recognition Issues in Swift

Tags: voice-recognition, speech

```
2016-08-14 20:49:11.603 ACRCloudDemo_Swift[2332:76253] HER
 INFO: cmd_ln.c(697): Parsing command line:
 \
 -hmm /Users/Administrator/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8B673B41-2CE3-4E43-B848-3651BD36A0F9/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/CB5DFC36-5AA6-4C79-B1B7-90734EC00C58/ACRCloudDemo_Swift.app/en-us/en-us \
 -lm /Users/Administrator/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8B673B41-2CE3-4E43-B848-3651BD36A0F9/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/CB5DFC36-5AA6-4C79-B1B7-90734EC00C58/ACRCloudDemo_Swift.app/en-us/en-us.lm.dmp \
 -dict /Users/Administrator/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8B673B41-2CE3-4E43-B848-3651BD36A0F9/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/CB5DFC36-5AA6-4C79-B1B7-90734EC00C58/ACRCloudDemo_Swift.app/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict 

Current configuration:
 [NAME] [DEFLT] [VALUE]
 -agc none none
 -agcthresh 2.0 2.000000e+00
 -allphone

 -allphone_ci no no
 -alpha 0.97 9.700000e-01
 -ascale 20.0 2.000000e+01
 -aw 1 1
 -backtrace no no
 -beam 1e-48 1.000000e-48
 -bestpath yes yes
 -bestpathlw 9.5 9.500000e+00
 -ceplen 13 13
 -cmn current current
 -cmninit 8.0 8.0
 -compallsen no no
 -debug 0
 -dict /Users/Administrator/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8B673B41-2CE3-4E43-B848-3651BD36A0F9/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/CB5DFC36-5AA6-4C79-B1B7-90734EC00C58/ACRCloudDemo_Swift.app/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict
 -dictcase no no
 -dither no no
 -doublebw no no
 -ds 1 1
 -fdict

 -feat 1s_c_d_dd 1s_c_d_dd
 -featparams

 -fillprob 1e-8 1.000000e-08
 -frate 100 100
 -fsg

 -fsgusealtpron yes yes
 -fsgusefiller yes yes
 -fwdflat yes yes
 -fwdflatbeam 1e-64 1.000000e-64
 -fwdflatefwid 4 4
 -fwdflatlw 8.5 8.500000e+00
 -fwdflatsfwin 25 25
 -fwdflatwbeam 7e-29 7.000000e-29
 -fwdtree yes yes
 -hmm /Users/Administrator/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8B673B41-2CE3-4E43-B848-3651BD36A0F9/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/CB5DFC36-5AA6-4C79-B1B7-90734EC00C58/ACRCloudDemo_Swift.app/en-us/en-us
 -input_endian little little
 -jsgf

 -keyphrase

 -kws

 -kws_plp 1e-1 1.000000e-01
 -kws_threshold 1 1.000000e+00
 -latsize 5000 5000
 -lda

 -ldadim 0 0
 -lifter 0 0
 -lm /Users/Administrator/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8B673B41-2CE3-4E43-B848-3651BD36A0F9/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/CB5DFC36-5AA6-4C79-B1B7-90734EC00C58/ACRCloudDemo_Swift.app/en-us/en-us.lm.dmp
 -lmctl

 -lmname

 -logbase 1.0001 1.000100e+00
 -logfn

 -logspec no no
 -lowerf 133.33334 1.333333e+02
 -lpbeam 1e-40 1.000000e-40
 -lponlybeam 7e-29 7.000000e-29
 -lw 6.5 6.500000e+00
 -maxhmmpf 30000 30000
 -maxwpf -1 -1
 -mdef

 -mean

 -mfclogdir

 -min_endfr 0 0
 -mixw

 -mixwfloor 0.0000001 1.000000e-07
 -mllr

 -mmap yes yes
 -ncep 13 13
 -nfft 512 512
 -nfilt 40 40
 -nwpen 1.0 1.000000e+00
 -pbeam 1e-48 1.000000e-48
 -pip 1.0 1.000000e+00
 -pl_beam 1e-10 1.000000e-10
 -pl_pbeam 1e-10 1.000000e-10
 -pl_pip 1.0 1.000000e+00
 -pl_weight 3.0 3.000000e+00
 -pl_window 5 5
 -rawlogdir

 -remove_dc no no
 -remove_noise yes yes
 -remove_silence yes yes
 -round_filters yes yes
 -samprate 16000 1.600000e+04
 -seed -1 -1
 -sendump

 -senlogdir

 -senmgau

 -silprob 0.005 5.000000e-03
 -smoothspec no no
 -svspec

 -tmat

 -tmatfloor 0.0001 1.000000e-04
 -topn 4 4
 -topn_beam 0 0
 -toprule

 -transform legacy legacy
 -unit_area yes yes
 -upperf 6855.4976 6.855498e+03
 -uw 1.0 1.000000e+00
 -vad_postspeech 50 50
 -vad_prespeech 10 10
 -vad_threshold 2.0 2.000000e+00
 -var

 -varfloor 0.0001 1.000000e-04
 -varnorm no no
 -verbose no no
 -warp_params

 -warp_type inverse_linear inverse_linear
 -wbeam 7e-29 7.000000e-29
 -wip 0.65 6.500000e-01
 -wlen 0.025625 2.562500e-02

INFO: cmd_ln.c(697): Parsing command line:
 \
 -lowerf 130 \
 -upperf 6800 \
 -nfilt 25 \
 -transform dct \
 -lifter 22 \
 -feat 1s_c_d_dd \
 -svspec 0-12/13-25/26-38 \
 -agc none \
 -cmn current \
 -varnorm no \
 -model ptm \
 -cmninit 40,3,-1 

Current configuration:
 [NAME] [DEFLT] [VALUE]
 -agc none none
 -agcthresh 2.0 2.000000e+00
 -alpha 0.97 9.700000e-01
 -ceplen 13 13
 -cmn current current
 -cmninit 8.0 40,3,-1
 -dither no no
 -doublebw no no
 -feat 1s_c_d_dd 1s_c_d_dd
 -frate 100 100
 -input_endian little little
 -lda

 -ldadim 0 0
 -lifter 0 22
 -logspec no no
 -lowerf 133.33334 1.300000e+02
 -ncep 13 13
 -nfft 512 512
 -nfilt 40 25
 -remove_dc no no
 -remove_noise yes yes
 -remove_silence yes yes
 -round_filters yes yes
 -samprate 16000 1.600000e+04
 -seed -1 -1
 -smoothspec no no
 -svspec 0-12/13-25/26-38
 -transform legacy dct
 -unit_area yes yes
 -upperf 6855.4976 6.800000e+03
 -vad_postspeech 50 50
 -vad_prespeech 10 10
 -vad_threshold 2.0 2.000000e+00
 -varnorm no no
 -verbose no no
 -warp_params

 -warp_type inverse_linear inverse_linear
 -wlen 0.025625 2.562500e-02

INFO: acmod.c(252): Parsed model-specific feature parameters from /Users/Administrator/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8B673B41-2CE3-4E43-B848-3651BD36A0F9/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/CB5DFC36-5AA6-4C79-B1B7-90734EC00C58/ACRCloudDemo_Swift.app/en-us/en-us/feat.params
 INFO: feat.c(715): Initializing feature stream to type: '1s_c_d_dd', ceplen=13, CMN='current', VARNORM='no', AGC='none'
 INFO: cmn.c(143): mean[0]= 12.00, mean[1..12]= 0.0
 INFO: acmod.c(171): Using subvector specification 0-12/13-25/26-38
 INFO: mdef.c(518): Reading model definition: /Users/Administrator/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8B673B41-2CE3-4E43-B848-3651BD36A0F9/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/CB5DFC36-5AA6-4C79-B1B7-90734EC00C58/ACRCloudDemo_Swift.app/en-us/en-us/mdef
 INFO: mdef.c(531): Found byte-order mark BMDF, assuming this is a binary mdef file
 INFO: bin_mdef.c(336): Reading binary model definition: /Users/Administrator/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8B673B41-2CE3-4E43-B848-3651BD36A0F9/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/CB5DFC36-5AA6-4C79-B1B7-90734EC00C58/ACRCloudDemo_Swift.app/en-us/en-us/mdef
 INFO: bin_mdef.c(516): 42 CI-phone, 137053 CD-phone, 3 emitstate/phone, 126 CI-sen, 5126 Sen, 29324 Sen-Seq
 INFO: tmat.c(206): Reading HMM transition probability matrices: /Users/Administrator/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8B673B41-2CE3-4E43-B848-3651BD36A0F9/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/CB5DFC36-5AA6-4C79-B1B7-90734EC00C58/ACRCloudDemo_Swift.app/en-us/en-us/transition_matrices
 INFO: acmod.c(124): Attempting to use PTM computation module
 INFO: ms_gauden.c(198): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /Users/Administrator/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8B673B41-2CE3-4E43-B848-3651BD36A0F9/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/CB5DFC36-5AA6-4C79-B1B7-90734EC00C58/ACRCloudDemo_Swift.app/en-us/en-us/means
 INFO: ms_gauden.c(292): 42 codebook, 3 feature, size: 
 INFO: ms_gauden.c(294): 128x13
 INFO: ms_gauden.c(294): 128x13
 INFO: ms_gauden.c(294): 128x13
 INFO: ms_gauden.c(198): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /Users/Administrator/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8B673B41-2CE3-4E43-B848-3651BD36A0F9/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/CB5DFC36-5AA6-4C79-B1B7-90734EC00C58/ACRCloudDemo_Swift.app/en-us/en-us/variances
 INFO: ms_gauden.c(292): 42 codebook, 3 feature, size: 
 INFO: ms_gauden.c(294): 128x13
 INFO: ms_gauden.c(294): 128x13
 INFO: ms_gauden.c(294): 128x13
 INFO: ms_gauden.c(354): 222 variance values floored
 INFO: ptm_mgau.c(476): Loading senones from dump file /Users/Administrator/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8B673B41-2CE3-4E43-B848-3651BD36A0F9/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/CB5DFC36-5AA6-4C79-B1B7-90734EC00C58/ACRCloudDemo_Swift.app/en-us/en-us/sendump
 INFO: ptm_mgau.c(500): BEGIN FILE FORMAT DESCRIPTION
 INFO: ptm_mgau.c(563): Rows: 128, Columns: 5126
 INFO: ptm_mgau.c(595): Using memory-mapped I/O for senones
 INFO: ptm_mgau.c(835): Maximum top-N: 4
 INFO: phone_loop_search.c(115): State beam -225 Phone exit beam -225 Insertion penalty 0
 INFO: dict.c(320): Allocating 137526 * 32 bytes (4297 KiB) for word entries
 INFO: dict.c(333): Reading main dictionary: /Users/Administrator/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8B673B41-2CE3-4E43-B848-3651BD36A0F9/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/CB5DFC36-5AA6-4C79-B1B7-90734EC00C58/ACRCloudDemo_Swift.app/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict
 INFO: dict.c(213): Allocated 1007 KiB for strings, 1662 KiB for phones
 INFO: dict.c(336): 133425 words read
 INFO: dict.c(342): Reading filler dictionary: /Users/Administrator/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8B673B41-2CE3-4E43-B848-3651BD36A0F9/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/CB5DFC36-5AA6-4C79-B1B7-90734EC00C58/ACRCloudDemo_Swift.app/en-us/en-us/noisedict
 INFO: dict.c(213): Allocated 0 KiB for strings, 0 KiB for phones
 INFO: dict.c(345): 5 words read
 INFO: dict2pid.c(396): Building PID tables for dictionary
 INFO: dict2pid.c(406): Allocating 42^3 * 2 bytes (144 KiB) for word-initial triphones
 INFO: dict2pid.c(132): Allocated 42672 bytes (41 KiB) for word-final triphones
 INFO: dict2pid.c(196): Allocated 42672 bytes (41 KiB) for single-phone word triphones
 INFO: ngram_model_arpa.c(77): No \data\ mark in LM file
 INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(142): Will use memory-mapped I/O for LM file
 INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(196): ngrams 1=19794, 2=1377200, 3=3178194
 INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(242): 19794 = LM.unigrams(+trailer) read
 INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(288): 1377200 = LM.bigrams(+trailer) read
 INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(314): 3178194 = LM.trigrams read
 INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(339): 57155 = LM.prob2 entries read
 INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(359): 10935 = LM.bo_wt2 entries read
 INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(379): 34843 = LM.prob3 entries read
 INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(407): 2690 = LM.tseg_base entries read
 INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(463): 19794 = ascii word strings read
 INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(99): 788 unique initial diphones
 INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(148): 0 root, 0 non-root channels, 56 single-phone words
 INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(186): Creating search tree
 INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(192): before: 0 root, 0 non-root channels, 56 single-phone words
 INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(326): after: max nonroot chan increased to 44782
 INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(339): after: 573 root, 44654 non-root channels, 47 single-phone words
 INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(157): fwdflat: min_ef_width = 4, max_sf_win = 25
 2016-08-14 20:49:12.787 ACRCloudDemo_Swift[2332:76253] 20:49:12.786 ERROR: AVAudioIONodeImpl.mm:784: SetOutputFormat: required condition is false: format.sampleRate == hwFormat.sampleRate
 2016-08-14 20:49:12.802 ACRCloudDemo_Swift[2332:76253] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false: format.sampleRate == hwFormat.sampleRate'
 *** First throw call stack:
 (
 0 CoreFoundation 0x000000010d484d85 exceptionPreprocess + 165
 1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x000000010f260deb objc_exception_throw + 48
 2 CoreFoundation 0x000000010d484bea +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
 3 libAVFAudio.dylib 0x00000001100bfff3 Z19AVAE_RaiseExceptionP8NSStringz + 176
 4 libAVFAudio.dylib 0x0000000110101aef _ZN17AVAudioIONodeImpl15SetOutputFormatEmP13AVAudioFormat + 533
 5 libAVFAudio.dylib 0x00000001100d2ead _ZN18AVAudioEngineGraph8_ConnectEP19AVAudioNodeImplBaseS1_jjP13AVAudioFormat + 2027
 6 libAVFAudio.dylib 0x00000001100d5df0 _ZN18AVAudioEngineGraph7ConnectEP11AVAudioNodeS1_mmP13AVAudioFormat + 322
 7 libAVFAudio.dylib 0x0000000110108a71 _ZN17AVAudioEngineImpl7ConnectEP11AVAudioNodeS1_mmP13AVAudioFormat + 301
 8 libAVFAudio.dylib 0x0000000110108ad8 -[AVAudioEngine connect:to:format:] + 83
 9 ACRCloudDemo_Swift 0x000000010c4b7737 _TFC18ACRCloudDemo_Swift7Decoder19startDecodingSpeechfFGSqVS_10Hypothesis_T_T + 1127
 10 ACRCloudDemo_Swift 0x000000010c4aca45 TFC18ACRCloudDemo_Swift14ViewController11viewDidLoadfT_T + 2149
 11 ACRCloudDemo_Swift 0x000000010c4ad892 TToFC18ACRCloudDemo_Swift14ViewController11viewDidLoadfT_T + 34
 12 UIKit 0x000000010de47984 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1198
 13 UIKit 0x000000010de47cd3 -[UIViewController view] + 27
 14 UIKit 0x000000010dd1dfb4 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 61
 15 UIKit 0x000000010dd1e69d -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 282
 16 UIKit 0x000000010dd30180 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
 17 UIKit 0x000000010dca4ed9 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4131
 18 UIKit 0x000000010dcab568 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1769
 19 UIKit 0x000000010dca8714 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
 20 FrontBoardServices 0x000000011216e8c8 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK + 24
 21 FrontBoardServices 0x000000011216e741 -[FBSSerialQueue performNext] + 178
 22 FrontBoardServices 0x000000011216eaca -[FBSSerialQueue performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
 23 CoreFoundation 0x000000010d3aa301 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION + 17
 24 CoreFoundation 0x000000010d3a022c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
 25 CoreFoundation 0x000000010d39f6e3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
 26 CoreFoundation 0x000000010d39f0f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
 27 UIKit 0x000000010dca7f21 -[UIApplication _run] + 402
 28 UIKit 0x000000010dcacf09 UIApplicationMain + 171
 29 ACRCloudDemo_Swift 0x000000010c4ba742 main + 114
 30 libdyld.dylib 0x000000010fd5492d start + 1
 )
 libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
 (lldb)
```

So, this is my output and a crash.... upon my app starting I call startDecoding speech...
 how can I get specific outputs in an organized way ???? help

It seems fixing this is simple, I'm working on it on my own and if someone can help that'd be great.

Comment: The log tells your device does not support required sample rate recording. You might want to experiment with different sample rate in sources. You also need to provide information about device you use (which ios is that, which phone).

Comment: How do I check for a valid sample rate? I would've debugged for hwFormat but this project mixes Swift and Obj-C and the Obj-C isn't able to be debugged.  iphone6plus emulator.

Comment: Try different values in tlsphinx sources on [this line](https://github.com/tryolabs/TLSphinx/blob/master/TLSphinx/Decoder.swift#L182)

Comment: The recordings hould be 16khz, does that mean 16000 should be the # i use?

Comment: Yes, you can try 16000 and 48000

Comment: Doesn't work.... any ideas  ?

Comment: Hi Nikolay. I haven't heard from you. Please respond.